# Angular routing on Tomcat involving Tuckey and Keycloak

Tags: angular, url-rewriting, keycloak, openid-connect

My Angular app runs on a Tomcat server under /webclient
A backend is provided via /frontend

I have created a Tuckey urlrewrite rule in the ROOT directory that rewrite everything which does not contain /frontend to /webclient/index.html to serve the angular app.

On startup of the app, Keycloak is involved to authenticate the user. As my app try to open /webclient/content the redirect url in the keycloak request is set to /webclient/content.

If the user is redirected, a 404 page not found error occure.

I have tried to provide a second Tucky which is located in the /webclient folder to redirect every request to http://.../webclient/index.html

This does not work. Any ideas how to make my app working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve this issue on tomcat.

I have changed the routing method to the # routing to solve this issue.